# ¿Cómo Ejecutar un .run en linux sin gksu ni ./?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, terminal

Verán, tengo un ejecutable .run (El ejecutable de la aplicación como tal, no el instalador)

Este está en una ruta `/home/usuario/software/ejecutable.run`

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de ejecutar el .run sin utilizar los comandos:

`gksu ~/software/ejecutable.run` (que uso en los `.desktop` para este tipo de sofware ya que en su mayoría requieren permisos de sudo)

ni tampoco ir hasta la ruta y ejecutar con `./`

`./ejecutable.run`

Es decir, hay alguna manera de ejecutarlo al igual que los `.sh` que utilizan el comando `sh`

EJM1: `sh /path/ejecutable.sh`

o los `.deb` que utilizan el comando `dpkg` con alguna de sus opciones

EJM2: `dpkg --option archivo.deb`

¿Existe alguna manera de ejecutar el `.run` de esta manera? algo como:

`comando --opcion /path/ejecutable.run` para este tipo de archivo

Pregunto esto para hacer un script que debe correr este tipo de archivo, **pero no es necesario ejecutar como sudo** ya que es algo sencillo dentro de la carpeta del mismo usuario, un "*mini servicio*" por esta razón no veo necesario ejecutar `gksu` y como el script toma la ruta absoluta del directorio tampoco requiere que se ejecute el `./`

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el comando `exec` funciona para llamar a ejecutar tanto ejecutables como scripts, si el ejecutable necesita de permisos de superusuario necesitas anteponer `sudo`

```
$ exec /path/ejecutable.run
```

Existen varias opciones que puedes utilizar para ello debes consultar su manual; para verlo basta con:

```
$ man exec
```